# iOS hitTest withEvent

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm attempting to get the reference to a UImageView that is underneath a masked UIImageView using hitTest withEvent. Here is what I have that is not working:

UIView A that contains 3 UIImageViews as subviews: panelOne, panelTwo, and panelThree. panelThree is takes up the entire frame but is masked into a triangle, revealing parts of panels one and two. So I need to detect when a user taps outside of that rectangle and send the touch to the appropriate UIImageView.

Code: (CollagePanel is a subclass of UIImageView)

```
-(void)triangleInASquare
{
    CGSize size = self.frame.size;
    CollagePanel *panelOne = [[CollagePanel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, size.width/2, size.height)];
    panelOne.panelScale = panelOne.frame.size.width/self.frame.size.width;
    panelOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    CollagePanel *panelTwo = [[CollagePanel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(size.width/2,0, size.width/2, size.height)];
    panelTwo.panelScale = panelOne.frame.size.width/self.frame.size.width;
    panelTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

    CollagePanel *panelThree = [[CollagePanel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, size.width, size.height)];
    panelThree.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    UIBezierPath* trianglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [trianglePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, panelThree.frame.size.height)];
    [trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(panelThree.frame.size.width/2,0)];
    [trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(panelThree.frame.size.width, panelTwo.frame.size.height)];
    [trianglePath closePath];

    // Mask the panels's layer to triangle.
    CAShapeLayer *triangleMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [triangleMaskLayer setPath:trianglePath.CGPath];
    triangleMaskLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    panelThree.layer.mask = triangleMaskLayer;

    //Add border
    CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    borderLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    borderLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    borderLayer.lineWidth = 6;
    [borderLayer setPath:trianglePath.CGPath];

    [panelThree.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempArray addObject:panelOne];
    [tempArray addObject:panelTwo];
    [tempArray addObject:panelThree];

    [self addGestureRecognizersToPanelsInArray:tempArray];
    [self addPanelsFromArray:tempArray];
    self.panelArray = tempArray;
}

-(void)handleTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer*) recognizer //coming from panel.imageView
{
    CGPoint tapPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self];
    NSLog(@"Location in self: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(tapPoint));
    NSLog(@"self.subviews: %@", self.subviews);
    UIView *bottomView = [self hitTest:tapPoint withEvent:nil];
    NSLog(@"Bottom View: %@", bottomView);
}
```

The NSLog of bottomView is always panelThree (the topmost panel). From what I understand the hit test should be returning the "bottom most" subview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you understand wrong. it will return the view that recognizes itself as touched and is nearest to your finger, nearer to the top.
If a view shall not recognize itself as touch for a certain point, you need to overwrite

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

for that view.

I think [Ole Begemann's Shapped Button](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/10/obshapedbutton-non-rectangular-buttons-on-the-iphone/) is a great example how to do so.

In your project this method could determine, if a point lies within the paths: [`CGPathContainsPoint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathContainsPoint).

---

Your `pointInside:withEvent:` might look like this:

```
#import "CollagePanel.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation CollagePanel
//
// ...
//
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint p = [self convertPoint:point toView:[self superview]];
    if(self.layer.mask){
        if (CGPathContainsPoint([(CAShapeLayer *)self.layer.mask path], NULL, p, YES) )
            return YES;
    }else {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.layer.frame, p))
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: So I had it backwards. In the pointInside method I can check to see if the touch is within the area and return NO if it is not. Will that allow the view below to be recognized?

Comment: yes, that is correct. if a view return no, the next view below will be asked.